# How to conditionally add route paths in akka-http?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I've got a series of paths that look like;

```
path("slides" / Segment) { segment =>
  getFromDirectory(s"${cfg.slidesDir}/$segment")
} ~
path("foo" / Segment) { segment =>
  getFromDirectory(s"${cfg.mypyPursDir}/$segment")
} ~
path("foo" / "images" / Segment) { segment =>
  getFromDirectory(s"${cfg.mypyPursImageDir}/$segment")
}
```

Under certain runtime conditions, some of these may not be active (e.g. production versus dev system). How does one enable this conditionality? I can imagine encoding it with if-else if there was a "dummy path" that didn't do anything, for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `List` of all the routes you want using standard Scala filtering and `List` building operations. Then use `concat` to create a route that includes all the selected routes.

```
val allRoutes: List[Route] = ???
val activeRoutes = allRoutes.filter(???)

def route =
  concat(activeRoutes:_*)
```

I prefer `concat` to `~` for chaining routes.